# Python Tkinter mixing radio and default user input box in canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter

I like to mixed my radio button selection with a few user input boxes.

I managed to output them separately but I can't combine them due to the one using canvas1.pack and another using row.pack.

[image]

This is my first radio button interface where user will select Auto or Manual and there is a box for user to input stock symbols manually.

[image]

This interface by default will show the default parameters such as volume or dividend amount and the user can change this parameter.

[image]

When I tried to put them together, they overlaps. The stock symbol input box was also shifted down. How can I move the parameter boxes below the auto and manual radio button without shifting the stock symbol box to the bottom?

Below is a sample of my code that is ready to be executed on jupyter.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk

#default filter values
parameter1 = 100000
parameter2 = 3

global answer 
global user_list

# Prepare parameters
fields = ['Min. parameter1', 'Min. parameter2', 'Min. 3parameter3',
          'Min. parameter4','Min. parameter5', 'Max. parameter6']
default_values = [parameter1,parameter2,parameter3,parameter4,
                  parameter5,parameter6]
captured_values = []

def on_closing():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        root.destroy()
        sys.stdout = orig_stdout
        f.close()
        sys.exit("Application closed by user")

def makeform(root, fields,default_values):
    entries = {}
    for i in range(len(fields)):
        row = tk.Frame(root)
        lab = tk.Label(row, width=24, text=fields[i]+": ", anchor='w')
        ent = tk.Entry(row)
        ent.insert(0, default_values[i])
        row.pack(side=tk.TOP, 
                 fill=tk.X, 
                 padx=5, 
                 pady=5)
        lab.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        ent.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, 
                 expand=tk.YES, 
                 fill=tk.X)
        entries[fields[i]] = ent
    return entries

# Button click event
def btn_click (e):
    global answer
    answer_choice = rdo_var.get()
    answer = rdo_txt[answer_choice]
    global user_list
    user_list = entry1.get()
    captured_values.append(e['Min. parameter1'].get())
    captured_values.append(e['Min. parameter2'].get())
    captured_values.append(e['Min. parameter3'].get())
    captured_values.append(e['Min. parameter4'].get())
    captured_values.append(e['Min. parameter5'].get())
    captured_values.append(e['Max. parameter6'].get())

    root.destroy()
    return answer

# Generate Tk class
root = tk.Tk()

# Screen size
root.geometry ('270x250')

# Screen title
root.title ('Enter parameters')

# set default parameters
ents = makeform(root, fields, default_values)

# box for manual input
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 350, height = 400)
canvas1.pack()   
entry1 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(165, 45, window=entry1)

# List radio button labels
rdo_txt = ['Auto','Manual']

# Radio button status
rdo_var = tk.IntVar ()

# Create and place radio buttons dynamically
for i in range (len (rdo_txt)):
    rdo = Radiobutton (root, value = i, variable = rdo_var, text = rdo_txt [i])
    rdo.place (x = 20, y = 15 + (i * 20))

# Create button
confirm_button = tk.Button (root, text = 'Confirm', command = (lambda e=ents: btn_click(e)))
confirm_button.place (x = 180, y = 200)

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
root.mainloop ()

if(answer == 'Manual'):
    print('Manual run selected.')
    manual_run = 1
    temp_user_list = []
    user_list = user_list.split(',')
    for i in range(len(user_list)):
        temp_user_list.append(user_list[i].strip().upper())
    print('Symbol(s) entered : ' + str(temp_user_list))
else:
    manual_run = 0
    print('Auto run selected.')
    
# new captured values
parameter1 = float(captured_values[0])
parameter2 = float(captured_values[1])
```

Comment: Hi, the code you provided doesn't work. For example, you are using `parameter3` to `parameter6` without defining their content. Same with `orig_stdout`. And could you explain a little bit more what you aspire to do? For example, do you want radio buttons in addition to a entry field for the manual option and other entry fields for your parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an expanded answer.

Complete code example.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk

#default filter values
parameter1 = 100000
parameter2 = 2
parameter3 = 3
parameter4 = 4
parameter5 = 5
parameter6 = 6

global answer 
global user_list

# Prepare parameters
fields = ['Min. parameter1', 'Min. parameter2', 'Min. parameter3',
          'Min. parameter4','Min. parameter5', 'Max. parameter6']
default_values = [parameter1,parameter2,parameter3,parameter4,
                  parameter5,parameter6]
captured_values = []

def on_closing():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        root.destroy()
        sys.stdout = orig_stdout
        f.close()
        sys.exit("Application closed by user")

def makeform(root, fields,default_values):
    entries = {}
    for i in range(len(fields)):
        row = tk.Frame(root)
        lab = tk.Label(row, width=28, text=fields[i]+": ", anchor='e')
        ent = tk.Entry(row)
        ent.insert(0, default_values[i])
        row.pack(side=tk.TOP, 
                 fill=tk.X, 
                 padx=5, 
                 pady=5)
        lab.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        ent.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, 
                 expand=tk.YES, 
                 fill=tk.X)
        entries[fields[i]] = ent
    return entries

# Button click event
def btn_click (e):
    global answer
    answer_choice = rdo_var.get()
    answer = rdo_txt[answer_choice]
    global user_list
    user_list = entry1.get()
    captured_values.append(e['Min. parameter1'].get())
    captured_values.append(e['Min. parameter2'].get())
    captured_values.append(e['Min. parameter3'].get())
    captured_values.append(e['Min. parameter4'].get())
    captured_values.append(e['Min. parameter5'].get())
    captured_values.append(e['Max. parameter6'].get())

    root.destroy()
    return answer

# Generate Tk class
root = tk.Tk()

# Screen size
root.geometry("410x260")

# Screen title
root.title('Enter parameters')

# set default parameters
ents = makeform(root, fields, default_values)

# box for manual input
manual = makeform(root, ['Manual input'], ["Enter value here"])
entry1 = manual["Manual input"]
entry1["background"] = "yellow" # make it standout
del manual

# List radio button labels
rdo_txt = ['Auto','Manual']

# Radio button status
rdo_var = tk.IntVar()

# Create and place radio buttons dynamically
for i in range (len (rdo_txt)):
    rdo = Radiobutton (root, value = i, variable = rdo_var, text = rdo_txt [i])
    rdo.place (x = 20, y = 15 + (i * 20))

# Create button
confirm_button = tk.Button (root, text = 'Confirm', command = (lambda e=ents: btn_click(e)))
confirm_button.place (x = 205, y = 220)

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
root.mainloop()

if(answer == 'Manual'):
    print('Manual run selected.')
    manual_run = 1
    temp_user_list = []
    user_list = user_list.split(',')
    for i in range(len(user_list)):
        temp_user_list.append(user_list[i].strip().upper())
    print('Symbol(s) entered : ' + str(temp_user_list))
else:
    manual_run = 0
    print('Auto run selected.')
    
# new captured values
parameter1 = float(captured_values[0])
parameter2 = float(captured_values[1])
```

Comment: Hi, I see the parameter boxes are out now, how can I get my manual input box out?

Comment: Do you mean you want entry1 out of canvas1?

Comment: I mean for auto and manual, I have a box for entering manual items. But choosing Auto or manual will still allow me to change the parameters for processing later.

Comment: I'll post the entire script so the changes made are in context. As for as I can see the code works, all objects are positioned and checkbuttons respond correctly.